# Reference specific library module flavor in app dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an app that has multiple flavors as well as a library module that has multiple flavors and I cant get the app dependency to find the module library flavors

library gradle flavors

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    libraryFlavor1 {}
    libraryFlavor2 {}
}
```

and my app flavors

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    appFlavor1 {}
    appFlavor2 {}
    appFlavor3 {}
}
```

in my dependencies for my app I reference it like this

```
implementation project(path: ':app:library')
```

When I do a gradle sync I get an error saying

```
Failed to resolve: project :app:library
Affected Modules: app
```

In the details it says `No matching variant of project :app:library was found.`

The library module previously didnt have any flavors and worked fine but now that I added additional flavors I cant get it to build.

I am not sure how to handle a library with multiple flavors along with an app with multiple flavors and make sure that app flavor is referencing the correct library flavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out, you have to add `matchingFallbacks` to the app build flavors for the specific library flavor that gradle cant find

```
productFlavors {
    appFlavor1 {
        matchingFallbacks = ["libraryFlavor1"]
    }
    appFlavor2 {
        matchingFallbacks = ["libraryFlavor2"]
    }
    appFlavor3 {
        matchingFallbacks = ["libraryFlavor1"]
    }
}
```